# Why is my file IO infinite looping in c?

Tags: c, file-io

I am new to file IO in c. I decided to write a simple script in c that copies a file to a new file for practice:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./myFile source destination");
        exit(-1);
    }

    FILE * src = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (src == NULL)
    {
        printf("source file not found", argv[1]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    FILE* dest = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    unsigned char c;
    do {
        c = fgetc(src);
        fputc(c, dest);
    } while (c != EOF);
}
```

However, I am getting an infinite loop. Is this because I never actually hit a character called EOF?

Also, is there a faster way to write this script aside from reading each character 1 at a time?

Comment: You could read a chunck at a time. You can provide a buffer and a size to be read. The actual number of bytes read are returned. You the write the data from the buffer to the output file. You stop when the number of bytes read is less than chunck size.

Comment: Thanks! Another question, when I use an int in lieu of an unsigned char, why do I get a strange symbol (ÿ) at the end of my destination file after copying?

Comment: Because you're passing `EOF` to `fputc()`, which expects a char, and "ÿ" happens to be what you get when you cast `EOF` to a char on your system.

Comment: Take a look at `sendfile(2)`, it's only down falling is it's not `POSIX`. Otherwise `mmap(2)` the two files is also a good way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare `c` as an `int` and it'll work.

`EOF` is not a valid value for a character, because if it were, the presence of that character in a file could mislead code into thinking that file has ended when it actually hasn't.  That's precisely why `fgetc()` actually returns an `int`, not a `char`.

---

**Edit:** Your code also has another bug: when `fgetc()` does return `EOF`, you pass that value to `fputc()` before ending the loop, causing an extra character to appear at the end of your output file.  (The extra character will be whatever you get when you cast `EOF` to `unsigned char` on your system, typically character `255 == 0xFF == (unsigned char) -1`.)  To fix that, you can rewrite your loop like this:

```
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(src)) != EOF) {
    fputc(c, dst);
}
```

or, if you don't like assigments in loop conditions:

```
while (1) {
    int c = fgetc(src);
    if (c == EOF) break;
    fputc(c, dst);
}
```

Anyway, it would be much more efficient to read and write the data in chunks using `fread()` and `fwrite()`, e.g. like this:

```
unsigned char buf[65536];
while (1) {
    int n = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), src);
    fwrite(buf, 1, n, dst);
    if (n < sizeof(buf)) break;  /* end of file or read error */
}
```

Also, it would be a good idea to include some error checking, since both reading and writing a file can fail for a variety of unexpected reasons.  You can use `ferror()` to tell whether an error has occurred on a particular I/O stream.

Answer (score 3):

EOF is not an `unsigned char` but an `int`. See the prototype of `fgetc`:

```
int fgetc(FILE *stream);
```